# How can I represent epsilon in a regular expression?

Tags: regex, epsilon

The text book teaches us to write regular expressions using the epsilon `(ε)` symbol, but how can I translate that symbol directly to code without having to completely rework my regular expression?

For instance, how would I write this regex which would catch all lowercase strings that either begin or end in `a` (or both).

Not 100% sure this is correct but...

((a|`epsilon`)[a-z]`*`a) | (a[a-z]`*`(a|`epsilon`))

So some strings that should match include:

```
a //single "a" starts or ends with "a"

aa //starts and ends with "a"

ab //starts with "a"

ba //ends with "a"

aba //starts and ends with "a"

aaaaaaaa //starts and ends with "a"

abbbbbbb //starts with "a"

bbbbbbba //ends with "a"

abbbbbba //starts and ends with "a"

asdfhgdu //starts with "a"

onoineca //ends with "a"

ahnrtyna //starts and ends with "a"
```

I only what to exchange `epsilon` for the correct symbol, I do not want to modify any part of the rest of the expression.  Also I want to be clear, I am not actually checking for the epsilon symbol, I want to have a choice of a character or nothing (well not nothing... epsilon).

**Does such a symbol exist?**

**Is what I want possible?**

Comment: If the character set (and language) supports it couldn't you just insert `ε` directly? What have you tried? What happened?

Comment: @typoknig :) Posted answer adhering to the QA structure of SO. Ignore it if you please.

Comment: @jensgram I think I might have been in error.  I thought it was working at first but now I am not sure.  Just to be clear, I am not check for the actual `epsilon` character.  See my revised question for a better regex example of what I am trying to do.

Comment: @typoknig Ah, in that case my answer is probably no good (and it was down-voted). Will remove :)

Comment: @jensgram thanks for your help anyways (I didn't down vote you) :)

Comment: @typoknig No problem. The answer was wrong anyway :)

Comment: @typoknig Perhaps you could add some concrete examples of strings to match (and strings *not* to match)? I'm a little confused, to say the least.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Just omit the , since it denotes the empty string:

```
([1-9]|)[0-9]*
```

There’s also a shortcut for this particular case:

```
([1-9]?)[0-9]*
```

The `?` means zero or one occurrences of the preceding token.

Comment: thanks, the example I gave in my question originally was not a good one, please look at my revised question.  Also, I am aware of `?`, but I was not sure if that was as close to an epsilon as I could get or not.

Comment: @typoknig: Once again, just omit the  symbol! Your new example introduces nothing that invalidates this technique, and in fact this technique will **always** work. Apart from that, your expression can  be made much simpler: `a[a-z]*|[a-z]*a`

Comment: thanks for your input, and I see now that the regex in my example could have been simpler.  The reason I wanted to use `epsilon` instead of some other symbol is that `epsilon` is what is used in my text book, so when I am discussing these expressions with others in class I want to be on the same page... using the same methods and symbols.  To that end I wanted the to use epsilon in a coded regex so I could check my work as I went along.

Comment: in the regex checker I use ( http://gskinner.com/RegExr/ ) an "empty string" after an "`|`" is not picked up, but that is not to say that it wouldn't work in some/most code.  Thanks for your help.

Comment: @typoknig: I suspect that that’s a bug since all major regex engines do in fact support this (I checked …, `foo|` works everywhere while the gskinner RegExr marks it as an error).